# Error after allocating array components in a derived type array

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran95

```
module sdata

    integer, parameter :: nblock = 2

    TYPE block_info

        REAL, ALLOCATABLE :: w(:)

    END TYPE block_info

    TYPE(block_info), TARGET :: block(nblock)

end module sdata





module variable

    use sdata

    REAL, POINTER :: w(:)

contains

    !.............................
    subroutine set_current(n)

    nullify(w)
    allocate(w(10))

    w(1:10)  => block(n)%w(1:10)

    end subroutine set_current
    !.............................

end module variable


subroutine make_sth

use variable
use sdata

real,allocatable,dimension(:)::wm,wp,ww
integer n

allocate(wm(5),wp(5),ww(5))


do n = 1,nblock

    block(n)%w(1:10) = (/ 1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6.,7.,8.,9.,10./)

    call set_current(n)

    wp(1:5) = w(1:5)
    wm(1:5) = w(6:10)

    ww = wp + wm

    do i = 1,5
        print*, 'block = ',n,'ww = ',ww(i)
    enddo

enddo

end subroutine make_sth


program main

use variable
use sdata

allocate(block(nblock)%w(10))

call make_sth

end program main
```

Here is my question. For nblock=1 code is perfectly running, however, if I increase nblock ie. to 2 it gives memory problems. How is it possible?

Comment: Please look at reducing the spacing of your code as all those blank lines make it hard to follow.

Comment: Please do not use uncertain phrases like "it gives memory problems". If it prints some error message, paste it into your question. Read [ask]

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at the allocation of the array components of the derived type.  In particular the line in the main program

```
allocate(block(nblock)%w(10))
```

This is not doing what you think it is, it seems.

What happens here is that the component `w` of the element `nblock` of `block` is allocated.  It isn't saying that the `nblock` components of `block` are *all* allocated to that size.  When `nblock` is 1, the effect is the same: no problem.

You need to allocate each element's component individually.  Which makes sense, as one would often like each element to have differently sized components, or varying allocation status.  There are several approaches for this, but I won't cover those here: there are other questions for that.

Comment: This is just like ABC of fortan90, thank you for remembering it. Sorry for this silly question.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
allocate(block(nblock)%w(10))
```

to

```
do i = 1, nblock
    allocate(block(i)%w(10))
end do
```

In you current code, you only allocate *one* element of `block`: either `block(1)%w(10)` if `nblock=1` or `block(2)%w(10)` if `nblock=2`. With the modification I propose you will allocate an array `w` inside of each element of `block`.